# Binding.scala: how to define checked in a Checkbox

Tags: scala, scala.js, binding.scala

I want to define a checkbox in **Binding.scala**, like:

```
 <input type="checkbox"
             checked={elem.checked}
             />
```

`elem.checked` can have any String value (even an empty):the checkbox is always `checked`.

How can I get

```
 <input type="checkbox"
             checked/>
```

if checked, resp.

```
 <input type="checkbox"/>
```

if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes , in XHTML 5, any text values means `true`.

Fortunately, Binding.scala XML literals allows attributes of `Boolean` type. If `elem.checked` is `false` (not `"false"`), the attribute will be removed.

Comment: thanks that works, only confusing thing is that the checkbox does not have a `checked` attribute when checked=true (in the inspector) see https://scalafiddle.io/sf/81rACVu/0

Comment: `checked={true}` set the property `checked` of the `<input>`, while `checked="checked"` set the attribute `checked`.

Comment: The property `defaultChecked` is mapped to the attribute `checked.

Comment: The property `checked` is not mapped to any attribute.